# c# finding active directory user by sAMAccount

Tags: c#, active-directory

Newbie to .Net 4.0.
We have a script that currently resets a user password with the following code:

```
 DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("myLdapString");

 DirectoryEntry ChgPwd = de.Children.Find("CN=" + "myuserid", "user");

 ChgPwd.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "newPWD" });

 ChgPwd.CommitChanges();
```

I want to change this so that I am pointing to the user using "sAMAccount=" rather than "CN=".  But changing that in my Find string above does not work.  Can someone help with the proper syntax for this change? Thanks

Comment: Isn't the attribute actually called `sAMAccountName`?

Comment: CN is usually the display name (e.g. "Homer Simpson"), but sAMAccountName is the login name (e.g. "simpsonh").  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yes I typod the attribue in my example.  I do have "sAMAccountName=" in the code but it does not work.

Comment: I do want to change the password of the login name rather than display name.

Comment: Also consider using `DirectorySearcher` instead of `DirectoryEntry.Find()`

Comment: Changing my logic to DirectorySearcher solved it and I also tried using the AccountManagement Namespace as recommended. Both solutions worked.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace to manage acitve directory account.

code like

```
using(PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain,
            TargetDomain,
            TargetDomainUserName,
            TargetDomainPassword))
 using(var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "somaloginname"))
{ 
userPrincipal.SetPassword(newPassword);
//or userPrincipal.ChangePassword
            userPrincipal.Save();
            }
```

[MSDN:UserPrincipal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)